# How to create a class of a template in other class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have some template:

```
template <Class T>
class CsHashCase{

   CsHashCase();
   ~CsHashCase();
   ...
};

template <class T> CsHashCase<T>::CsHashCase()
{
   ...
}

template <class T> CsHashCase<T>::~CsHashCase()
{
   ...
}
```

Inside of some class I need to create a class of this template:

```
#include "TmHashCase.h"

class CsSomeClass{

   CsHashCase<int> * GbHashCase;

   CsSomeClass();  // Constructor

};

// Constructor
CsSomeClass::CsSomeClass()
{
   GbHashCase = new CsHashCase<int>; 
}
```

But the compiler shows me an errors:

```
undefined reference to `CsHashCase<int>::CsHashCase()
undefined reference to `CsHashCase<int>::CsHashCase()
```

How to do it right?

Comment: Include the header file `CsHashCase` is define in?

Comment: Make sure that your template decleration and definition is in one file for CsHashCase

Comment: Why spelling `template` with an _a_ 3 times in your question when you write it correctly in your code???

Comment: This error is commonly caused by implementing function templates in a source file. They (nearly always) need to go in a header, included in every translation unit that uses them.

Comment: @Mike Seymour Thanks, I add #include "TmHashCase.h" in cpp file and all works! Thanks to all others!